# Is there a function to get the size of std::vector's element directly?

Tags: c++, vector, size, std, sizeof

`vector::size()` gives the amount of elements in a vector, but how do I get the size of a single element?

This is what I mean in practice:

```
std::vector<char>   --> 1
std::vector<int>    --> 4
std::vector<double> --> 8
```

The next line only works when the vector has at least one element

```
int size_of_element = sizeof(myVec[0]);
```

If there's no elements in the vector, it won't work. Is there some function to get the size of the type directly?

Edit: Okay apparently it does work.

Comment: `sizeof(std::vector<YourType>::value_type)`

Comment: `The next line only works when the vector has at least one element If there's no elements in the vector, it won't work.` Nope, the expression isn't evaluated, only it's type is looked at.

Comment: `sizeof(myVec[0])` may fail for `vector<bool>`. `sizeof(std::vector<YourType>::value_type)` is universal.

Comment: And in C++11 and later, you can use `decltype(myVec)` instead of spelling out `std::vector<YourType>` explicitly: `int size_of_element = sizeof(decltype(myVec)::value_type);`

Comment: If you want to get size of the item from a variable then you can use `sizeof(decltype(myVec)::value_type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone said in the comments:

```
sizeof(std::vector<double>::value_type)
```

or

```
sizeof(decltype(myVec)::value_type)
```

The latter requires C++11, but does not require spelling out the `std::vector` type again.

In contrast to `sizeof(myVec[0])` this does always give the correct result. This is not the case for the former, because there is an exception for `std::vector<bool>` which behaves differently than other `std::vector`'s and in particular `myVec[0]` does not return a `bool&`.

Besides that point `sizeof(myVec[0])` is always ok, though. Even if the vector would be empty at the point where you are using that expression, the argument to `sizeof` is an unevaluated operand. The expression `myVec[0]` is not actually evaluated and the vector element is not actually received. Instead only the type of the result is calculated and from the type the size of the type can be determined. So there is no cause for undefined behavior here if the vector is empty.
And how could there be? `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, but at compile time we may not even know what is in the vector. The vector as an object usually does not even exist at compile time.

Comment: That second one is exactly what I was looking for.